# Need Syntax help in passing CTE in SQL query in Azure databricks

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

I am reading the `employee` table from SQL Server, but I get this error while using `WITH` clause in query and code is working fine if I remove WITH clause in query.

Note: `WITH` clause is mandatory to use in my query to optimize the query performance

```
from pyspark.sql import Sparksession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

query =f"""(
WITH cte_emp AS
(Select ename,eid, eaddress from 
employee)
select * from 
cte_emp)"""

source =spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcurl, table=query,properties=connection


jdbc_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/my_db").option("dbtable", "query").option("user", "my_username").option("password", "my_password").load()
```

This is the error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLserverException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'

Comment: with isn't mandatory, for many years we existed without it... just use `Select ename,eid, eaddress from employee`

Comment: we are migrating azure sql query(copy activity) to databricks notebooks and we have WITH clause in old queries for performance optimization and we need to use same structure query in databricks also

Comment: try removing the first `(` and the last `)` so that W (of WITH) is the first character

Comment: I tried with removing ( and  )  still facing same error

Comment: ok, as a test only, to rule out other error sources try my first suggestion

Comment: @bigdatatechie , Please note that your question states that the source is on SQL server, but in the options you are accessing jdbc:mysql .

Comment: Hi, I provided a syntax example  how  we are reading the data from sql server there is no issue from connection side I am able to pull the data if I select columns without WITH clause

Comment: While you **might** need use of CTEs in some complex queries to assist in performance tuning - it simply isn't true in general as (with some exceptions) a "derived table" sub-query can provide exactly the same execution plan. I think you simply want to avoid refactoring your queries - and that isn't unreasonable, but better IMHO to state the real reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server does not accept WITH clauses in subqueries, so you need to bypass that.

Split the CTE query like this:

```
prepare_query = f"""
WITH cte_emp AS (
Select 
* 
from [dbo].[Employees]
) """
query = f"""
select * 
from cte_emp
"""
```

And then use "prepareQuery" option for JDBC:

```
jdbc_df = spark.read.format("jdbc"). \
    option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306/my_db"). \
    option("prepareQuery",prepare_query). \
    option("query", query). \
    option("user", "my_username"). \
    option("password", "my_password").load()
```

Data is returned correctly.

Source - Spark documentation - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html